# How to compile a file to view in .pdf file in texStudio

Tags: texstudio, paths

How to compile a file to view in .pdf file in texStudio?
I am using foxit reader as my pdf viewer. I can't compile after I text it.
The below is the error display in the foxit reader after I compile it.

> Check if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.